# uBoot recursive variables, have I simply misunderstood

Tags: u-boot, qnap

This feels like I've just misunderstood a basic concept:

My real-world case looks like:

```
setenv nbootcmd .....various options
setenv fbootcmd ..... various options
setenv bootcmd \${nbootcmd}
```

But, as I don't want to reboot every attempt, I reduced it to:

```
 U-Boot 1.1.4 (Oct 27 2010 - 16:50:30) Marvell version: 3.4.4
Marvell>> setenv cmd printenv cmd\;printenv icmd\;version
Marvell>> setenv icmd \${cmd}
Marvell>> run cmd
cmd=printenv cmd;printenv icmd;version
icmd=${cmd}

U-Boot 1.1.4 (Oct 27 2010 - 16:50:30) Marvell version: 3.4.4
Marvell>> run icmd
## Error: "cmd;printenv" not defined
## Error: "icmd;version" not defined
```

Now I'm expecting **run cmd** and **run icmd** to behave the same.

Now I gather I can achieve the same effect with:

```
Marvell>> setenv icmd run cmd
Marvell>> run icmd
cmd=printenv cmd;printenv icmd;version
icmd=run cmd

U-Boot 1.1.4 (Oct 27 2010 - 16:50:30) Marvell version: 3.4.4
```

but I can't see why the first form does not work. I'm asking to learn what I've misunderstood about uBoot rather than find a hack that works?

Comment: The operand of the **run** command should be an environment variable, and not another command. **printenv** is a U-Boot command, rather than a variable. So `run icmd` (in your first version) first performs expansion of the recursive variable, and then tries to perform `run printenv cmd;printenv icmd;version`, which is invalid. Similarly, `printenv icmd` is a command with a valid operand that is a variable, whereas `printenv ${cmd}` is not (after the string substitution). BTW it's not microBoot nor "*uBoot*", but U-Boot for Universal-Boot.

Comment: Ahh, yes thanks .... it was one of those situations , you keep looking at it and seeing the same thing, bit like those fake 3d images ... you can't see it, can't see it ... suddenly you see it, now you can't unsee it . Now it seems obvious.

Comment: Would you like to make that an answer, rather than a comment, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive variable in U-Boot is handled as simple string substitution in a manner similar to a **#define** macro with the C preprocessor. There is no shell involved, or any execution layering. The string substitution has precedence, and the replacement (of the recursive variable) is performed before the command (operating on that recursive variable) is executed.

So `run icmd` (in your first version) will first perform expansion of the recursive variable

```
run ${cmd}
```

and then tries to perform

```
run printenv cmd;printenv icmd;version
```

which is invalid.
The operand of the **run** command should be an environment variable, and not another command. **printenv** is a U-Boot command, rather than a variable.
U-Boot's CLI seems to get confused sometimes by such malformed compound commands, and may display less-than-perfect diagnostic messages.

Similarly, `printenv icmd` is a command with a valid operand that is a variable, whereas `printenv ${cmd}` is not (after the string substitution).